# How to use both forms and windows/domain authentication in one ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

Its not an original question. There is already a batch of articles describing this problem and solution for it. They all are dated back to times of .Net Framework 1.1 and IIS 6.0 and are not really helping with all the membership and role providers stuff we have nowadays. But lets get closer to the problem.

The problem is short.
You have an intranet site using Windows authentication and it works just fine. All you want is to give access to this site to users from their homes and to users who don`t have Windows based workstation.

Duplicate the whole site would be cumbersome because all the application except Login part would work well just if appropriate information would be saved in cookie on Login step.

You are welcome with any suggestions.

Comment: Are you using Active Directory and can use the Active Directory forms provider?

Comment: Currently we are not, but we can if it helps. So we would be glad to here your advice.

Comment: AD is the way to go if you can; the downside is that you have to login in both modes, but the upside is all of the code is the same, and you can use your AD store as the authentication/authorization source.  I'd recommend it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say if internal users are authenticated or not, so, as it's an intranet I'm going to assume they are, via integrated authentication.

The simplest way would be to leave it as is, and turn on [digest authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754104%28WS.10%29.aspx) if you are in a domain environment in addition to integrated authentication - this would prompt users not on the intranet with a username/password popup and they can login with their domain credentials.

If you don't have a domain - then how is it an intranet site? How are users authenticated? If you're in a workgroup scenario, where users have login details on their own box, and login details on the intranet server (in which case moving to AD would be better all round - no need to keep the passwords in sync, or deactivate user accounts in multiple places when people leave) then mixing Integrated authentication with [Basic Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009%28WS.10%29.aspx) would do the same thing - however if you're going to use Basic Authentication then you will need to add an SSL certificate to the site to stop usernames and passswords being sniffed - Basic Authentication sends them in plain text.

Comment: We are in domain. Using Integrated Windows Authentication to free user from entering any information on entering the site. So the variant with turning on Digest authentication can work for us. Thanks.

Comment: I would put serious consideration into putting an SSL certificate on the site. Whilst digest auth doesn't use plain text for credentials I would assume that, as it's an intranet, you don't want the site contents leaked to anyone hacking wifi in Starbucks :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you could consider is if you can use Active Directory, there is a provider to use the AD store for security, that would work for both.

HTH.

Comment: I doubt that will work, depending on setup System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() will return an authenticated account - the app pool account. Not what you may be expecting!

Comment: So, it means that thats the line of code, that can be called on client side to get user information, send it back and sign in the user if he is present in User List? Did i got everything right?

Comment: By client if you mean ASP.NET server code, yes that's what I meant.  But I believe @blowdart is correct - since it's forms authentication, the current user will be the system account representing the site, not the current user.  Try it out, set authentication mode to forms, and add System.Windows.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() and check out the info, is it the current user logged in?